# How to make this electrical main safe

Tags: electrical, safety

An older home has a strung electrical main. The main connects with exposed lugs on the roof above the deck. Not only is the height and location unsafe, while working on the roof today I noticed that the insulation on the **main** electrical lines is deteriorated. This is **before** the meter and my main breaker.

Here you can see the exposed main lugs. This is about 8.5' from the deck surface. Somebody carrying a tall object such as a pole or a ladder or a piece of pipe could easily hit these.

[image: exposed main lugs]

I am in the process of re-locating the main for the home to a different, safer location. At that time I will need the power company to handle and relocate this main line. However, I am quite concerned above the safety of this line as-is. You can clearly see the deteriorated insulation in one of the legs of the wire. The neutral is completely exposed and the red conductor is significantly worn.

[image: deteriorated insulation]

Is there anything I can do to address this until the utility company can relocate the line? I was considering a spray-on electrical insulator. I am not properly equipped to actually be in contact with this wire to apply tapes or paint-on insulation.

Comment: The black cuddled up against the neutral is a bit scary if the insulation has failed there also.  Air is a dandy insulator.  I might be tempted to stick a wooden wedge between the black and white near the peckerhead (sorry weatherhead) and then leave it for your electrician.

Comment: **Don't touch it**.  Slowly walk away and call an Electrician, or the local power company.  You do not want to mess with this. Remember, there is no overcurrent protection on these lines, if you touch them you will be shocked until the transformer blows or the line burns.

Comment: +1 for the don't touch warning. I would add don't go near it. Don't try to do anything to it. Typically the power company is resonsible for this part of the service. Call them explain the situation they will most likely send someone out quickly.

Comment: The electrical company almost certainly won't even TOUCH your work unless you are a licensed electrician with a permit (that's absolutely true in MD, can't speak for all states).  If you call them up as Harry Homeowner without a signed, inspected and approved permit they'll send you packing.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo A licensed electrical contractor will be adding the new main panel, though I haven't pulled the permit. I was thinking that, since the power company needs to address this safety issue anyhow it might be expedient to have them relocate at the same time.

Comment: The power company usually doesn't install the main.  (at least around here) They leave that up to the electrician.  In my case, when I had my panel upgraded, the electrician pulled the permit, installed the new 200A meter and panel, AND a new main tower, temporarily tied the old main tower to the new meter, then BGE came out (after we passed inspection) and hooked up the new main tower to the main line and meter.

Comment: @MatthewPK The contractor should *always* be the one to pull the permit. If they won't it's a major warning sign that you should not be using them (eg, maybe they have no license/insurance so can't get a permit themselves). Ref http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2009-10-23/entertainment/0910210868_1_contractor-permit-inspector

Comment: @gregmac you're right usually. In this case the contractor is my dad ;-)

Comment: That junction you see is the boundary between the power company's problem, and your main.  Except in a wind storm, there is no 'problem'.  Just take care, and get it done right, soon.

Comment: @MatthewPK spraying something is a really bad idea. a cloud of aerosol something surrounding exposed, live conductors sounds like a great way to cause an arc!

Comment: If your dad is a licensed electrical contractor, shouldn't he already know the answer to this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No. There is nothing you can, or should do to fix this.

Don't touch it, don't go near it, don't even look at it anymore.  Get off the roof, and call the local power company or an Electrician.

Service entrance cables do not have overcurrent protection and will shock you until the transformer blows, the wire burns and breaks, or contact with the line has been broken. All of which will likely happen long after you are dead.

Comment: In this case, maximum safety is to do nothing. My lineman grandfather would tell you to run in the opposite direction, find a phone and give his boss a call.

Comment: The most likely danger is that a wire will short, it will scare you, and you'll fall off the roof.

Comment: WHAT TESTER SAID!  DO NOT TOUCH!!

Comment: Hey, I'm dropping by PK's house later. Do you guys think it's OK to touch those lines?